# Define subspaces $U_1 \leq V$ and $U_2 \leq V$, can I then claim $\dim(U_1+U_2)=\dim V$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose the following:

- ($v_1,...,v_m$) is a basis of $V$
- ($w_1,...,w_n$) is a basis of $W$
- $T \in L(V,W)$

If I were to define two subspaces $U_1:=\{\forall v\in V | Tv \in \text{span}(w_1,...,w_k)$, with $1\leq k < n\}$ and $U_2:= \{ \forall v\in V | Tv \in \text{span}(w_{k+1},...,w_n) \}$.

Would it be possible for me to conclude form here that: $\dim(U_1+U_2)=\dim  V=m$? I think should be able to make this claim, but I am not quite sure how to show it.

Comment: Sorry in advance if the question is not well formulated.

Comment: Sorry, there are some issues with my proof. I am deleting my answer. If I can fix it, I will post it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is false.

Consider $T: \Bbb R^2 \rightarrow \Bbb R^2$ such that $e_1 \mapsto e_1 + e_2$ and $e_2 \mapsto e_1 + e_2$. Now let $w_1 = e_1$ and $w_2 = e_2$, $k=1$. You will find $U_1 = U_2 = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Since the $w_k$ form a basis, in particular they are linearly independent. Therefore, your subspaces $U_1$ and $U_2$ obey $U_1\cap U_2 = \{0\}$. It follows that $\dim (U_1+U_2) = \dim U_1 +\dim U_2$. Since the $w_k$ also span you get that your $U_1\oplus U_2 = V$ which yields your claim.